# Groovy: command chain with dots and multiple assignments

Tags: groovy, command, chain, multiple-assignment

I'm trying to understand why command chaining without dots is not working with multiple assignments. For example this dummy code:

```
def (one, two) = String.valueOf 12 trim() iterator()
```

Raises:

> Script1.groovy: 2: expecting EOF, found '12' @ line 2, column 33.
> def (one, two) = String.valueOf 12 trim() iterator()

Of course if I add the dot then everything is fine

Comment: This compiles (but does not properly work) with Groovy 3.0.5 - what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using latest  version of groovy 2.5 -> 2.5.13

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm just trying to implement a nice DSL, last chained method returning a list of two maybe three objects. I want clients/consumers of that DSL to be able to nicely "unpack" the list using multiple assignments.

Comment: `def (one, two) = String.valueOf 12 trim()` works for me in groovy 3.0.7, also works in 3.0.5, and `def (one, two) = String.valueOf(12).trim()` works in 2.5.9